# Can't cast SqlGeography when withdrawing data from DB

Tags: c#, .net-core, geo, linq2db

I can't get `SqlGeography` object from MS SQL DB, I use .net core app and linq2db as the provider, but I have an exception:
"Can't create 'GIS_CH_DB.sys.geography' type or '' specific type for Geometry."

But I'm use

```
var provider = (SqlServerDataProvider)DataConnection.GetRegisteredProviders()[LinqToDB.ProviderName.SqlServer2014];
            provider.AddUdtType<SqlGeography>("Geography", null, LinqToDB.DataType.Udt);
            provider.AddUdtType<SqlGeometry>("Geometry", null, LinqToDB.DataType.Udt);
```

which should cast SQLGeography to correct object. Does somebody know how to solve this issue?

Comment: First of all, why do you call AddUdtType for spatial types? linq2db already register them automatically or if it is not happening, you can register it manually using `SqlServerTools.ResolveSqlTypes(assembly)`. If it will not help, post some examples, that give you those errors.

Comment: @DLuk, thanks for the advice but unfortunately it didn't help. An issue that I have columns with type `SqlGeometry` in GIS Db but in .net Core `SqlTypes` doesn't support. So I used unofficial SqlType libs. So issue that when I want to get value `SqlGeometry` or `SqlGeography` from DB table, appear exception:
"Can't create 'GIS_CH_DB.sys.geography' type or '' specific type for Geometry."

Comment: Which package you use? We test linq2db with this one https://github.com/dotMorten/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types and it works in our tests. So wether you use something else of we need to add more tests.

Comment: Probably you shold track this issue https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/issues/1836 for now

Comment: So as you can see from linked issue - it is probably due to missing assembly version redirects. SqlClient uses hardcoded references to pretty old version of types assembly

Comment: @DLuk Hello, sorry for the late answer. I use also github.com/dotMorten/Microsoft.SqlServer.Types. 
I tried 
`SqlServerTools.ResolveSqlTypes(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(SqlGeometry)))` in Startup file but it didn't help.

How can I change the reference for SqlClient?

Comment: Have you tried to add binding redirects?

Comment: @DLuk, binding redirects don't work in .net Core.

Comment: ok, I was able to reproduce it. Will report soon how to fix it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: added retrown instead of return null

As it was mentioned in comments, this is due to version conflicts between spatial types assembly (`Microsoft.SqlServer.Types`), requested by sql client and actual assembly you have. While for .net framework application you can handle it using binding redirects, for .net core you cannot do it because:

- no binding redirects in .net core
- even if there will be any - they will not work due to different public keys

You need to register custom assembly resolver to fix it (based on https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/290#issuecomment-280451104):

```cs
// somewhere in your init code
AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Resolving += OnAssemblyResolve;

Assembly OnAssemblyResolve(AssemblyLoadContext assemblyLoadContext, AssemblyName assemblyName)
{
  try
  {
    AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Resolving -= OnAssemblyResolve;
    return assemblyLoadContext.LoadFromAssemblyName(assemblyName);
  }
  catch
  {
    if (assemblyName.Name == "Microsoft.SqlServer.Types")
      return typeof(SqlGeography).Assembly;
    throw;
  }
  finally
  {
    AssemblyLoadContext.Default.Resolving += OnAssemblyResolve;
  }
}
```

I will update linq2db documentation to mention it and also check if we can improve this situation on our side